# Does each creator coin require a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, openzeppelin

I'm trying to build an app where each user who signs up gets their own coin, similar to how users who sign up for [BitClout](https://bitclout.com/one_pager.pdf) are given their own, unique Creator Coin (continuous token w/ a Bancor bonding curve).

Would this require creating a new smart contract for each user? I've been poking around at the OpenZeppelin ERC20 contract templates and I've been wondering whether a new contract would have to be generated each time a user signs up, so each one could have a unique coin.

Comment: What type of coin they own? ERC20, ERC721, something else. What's the use of their coin? If all users will use the same contract you can deploy it once and then create a [minimal proxy](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1167) for each user.

Comment: Each user would have an ERC20 coin which can be bought and sold. For example, user Alice would have an alice coin, and this alice coin could be bought and sold by anybody on the platform

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you could use ERC-1155.

> a novel standard for multi-tokens, allowing for a single contract to represent multiple fungible and non-fungible tokens, along with batched operations for increased gas efficiency.

There's an OpenZeppelin template, see https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/erc1155